# OrmLite Foreign Collection to List

Tags: orm

I try to use foreign collections in ORMLite. However, I dont know how to convert it into list. I try to do something like this :

```
public class Car implements Serializable {
@DatabaseField(columnName = "carId" , generatedId = true, id=true)
private int id;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "carNumber")
private String mNumber;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "carName")
private String mName;
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true,columnName = "carParts")
private Collection<Part> mParts;

ArrayList<Part> parts = new ArrayList<>(mParts);

public ArrayList<Part> getParts() {
        return parts;
    }

public void setParts(ArrayList<Part> parts) {
    this.parts = parts;
}
```

but when I try to use it I get exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: collection == null
```

at this line :

```
ArrayList<Part> parts = new ArrayList<>(mParts);
```

please, help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple - you have to wait until mParts will be initialized by ORMLite library, then you can create ArrayList from it.

```
public ArrayList<Part> getParts() {
   return new ArrayList<>( mParts );
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The reason is simple - you have to wait until mParts will be initialized by ORMLite library, then you can create ArrayList from it.